# Halyard: Deploy changes to Spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker-halyard

We have deployed spinnaker using halyard in dev environment. we need to add new kubernetes account from TEST cluster.

hal config is updated with new kubernetes account ( from TEST environment )
Then ran 'hal deploy apply' to deploy the changes. only redis deployment successful. Other services are shown with deploy failure. see below

```
^ Apply deployment
  Generating all Spinnaker profile files and endpoints: Waiting on deployments to complete
+ Deploy spin-redis
  Success
- Apply deployment
  Failure
+ Deploy spin-redis
  Success
^ Deploy spin-clouddriver

^ Deploy spin-front50
  Deploying spin-front50 with kubectl: Running kubectl apply on the resource definition...
^ Deploy spin-orca

- Deploy spin-deck
  Failure
^ Deploy spin-echo
  Deploying spin-echo with kubectl: Running kubectl apply on the resource definition...
^ Deploy spin-gate
  Deploying spin-gate with kubectl: Running kubectl apply on the resource definition...
- Deploy spin-igor
  Failure
^ Deploy spin-kayenta
  Deploying spin-kayenta with kubectl: Running kubectl apply on the resource definition...
- Deploy spin-rosco
  Failure
Problems in Global:
! ERROR Failed to deploy manifest:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: spin-clouddriver-files-1220510258
  namespace: spinnaker
........
```

how do i apply new change using hal. please let me know

Comment: Can you please provide more details on the error that you're getting?